# What is the proper procedure on compiling templates and/or compiling with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, makefile

I have some template classes I've written that are dependencies for several other classes I need to compile. I have a few options as to how I can do this in my Makefile:

1. Each class that requires a template lists its template requirements. This has the drawback of needing to recreate the dependency tree every time I want to add a new class.
2. Make the templates into target somehow. Either by compiling them, or by making some shadow dependency tree that does not compile anything, but simply forces a recompilation in the event of one of the templates becoming modified.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Make does not deal with classes, it deals with files. You treat a file containing templates as you would any other header file.

Comment: As in list it as a required file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "required file" - make has no such concept. You would normally make it a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil Butterworth mentioned in a comment, make deals with files. Say you have a `foo.cpp` and a `bar.h`. The latter contains your template. And the former might do, for example:

```
#include "bar.h"
class Foo : public Bar<Widget> { [...] };
```

While your `Foo` class inherits and thus depends on your `Bar` template class, you are also already declaring your file dependencies with your `#include`s.

It's those same file dependencies that you specify in your Makefile:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp bar.h
        g++ -I. -o foo.o foo.cpp
```

For this rule, make expects that the commands you specify create `foo.o`, based on the `foo.cpp` and `bar.h` files. If you've already built `foo.o` once, and those dependencies haven't changed, make knows it can skip the rule altogether.

It may seem tedious to specify file dependencies twice, but luckily dependencies in your Makefile can be automatically generated from `#include`s in your source code by GCC using the `-M` command-line parameter. You can read about this in the `gcc(1)` manpage. Simply take GCC's output, save it somewhere, typically `foo.d`, and `include` that in your Makefile.

With some wizardry, you can automate the generation of `*.d` dependency files in the same Makefile that builds your application.

Answer (score 1):

On option 2, you can compile a template instantiation using g++. For example, suppose you had:

```
// my_class.hpp
template <typename T1, class Container, typename Compare>
class my_class {
    // ...
};
```

and in your code you used `my_class<long, std::vector<long>, std::greater<long> >`. With g++ you can compile the instantiation of `my_class<long, std::vector<long>, std::greater<long> >` into an object file:

```
// my_class_long_long_vector_greater_instantiation.cpp
#include "my_class.hpp"

template class my_class<long, std::vector<long>, std::greater<long> >;
```

Then, in your `Makefile` near the bottom you add:

```
my_class_long_long_vector_greater_instantiation.o: my_class.hpp
```

If any target depends on `my_class_long_long_vector_greater_instantiation.o`, and the declaration of template `my_class` has changed (the `my_class.hpp` file was changed), then GNU make will re-compile `my_class_long_long_vector_greater_instantiation.cpp`, hence re-instantiate `my_class<long, std::vector<long>, std::greater<long> >`.

See also: [Where's the Template?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html)